# What is the correct way to set the short name for a multi-language app?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App which will be released in multiple languages.
In Package.appxmanifest under Visual Assets with "Tile Images and Logos" selected from the tree on the left there is an option `Short name:` where I can put in the text which appears on the start menu icon.

[image: Package.appxmanifest showing the "Short name:" field]

What is the correct way to relate this to the language resource files so the name will be correct for the language of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form *ms-resource:* where  is the name of the string in your resources. This is documented in "How to load string resources" here: [HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465248(v=win.10).aspx#loading_strings_from_the_windows_store_app_manifest.) | [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965323(v=win.10).aspx#loading_strings_from_the_windows_store_app_manifest.).